# For a hermitian element $a$ in a $C^*$-algebra, show that $\|a^{2n}\| = \|a\|^{2n}$

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^*$-algebra. Suppose that $a \in \mathcal{A}$ with the property that $a^* = a$ (that is, suppose that $a$ is *hermitian*).

> I would like to show that $\|a^{2n}\| = \|a\|^{2n}$ for all $n \ge 1$.

This fact is stated in Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*, and I'm having trouble proving it. Here's what I have so far: the $n =1 $ base cases just uses the basic $C^*$-algebra property:

$$\|a^2\| = \|a^* a \| = \|a\|^2.$$

But now I get stuck on the induction step (assume we have $\|a^{2n}\| = \|a\|^{2n}$, show that $\|a^{2n + 2}\| = \|a\|^{2n + 2}$). I have been trying to give myself some insight by studying small cases, for instance, $n = 3$:

$$\|a^6\| = \|(a^3)^2\| = \|a^3\|^2,$$

where the last equality follows from the base case. But then I end up with an odd exponent inside the norm. This is what is really giving me trouble.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know the result to be true for $\| a^{2^n}\|=\|a\| ^{2^n}$ which you can do indeed with induction. I believe that this is also stated in Conway's proposition 1.11 on page 234.

Comment: More generally, if $a$ is normal then $\|a^n\|=\|a\|^n$ for each positive integer $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is true for all powers, even or odd.

Proposition 1.11e on page 234 says that $\|a\|=r(a)$ for any Hermitian $a$, where $r(a) $ is the [spectral radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of $a$, that is $r(a) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \|a^k\|^{1/k}$.

Since $a^{n}$ is also Hermitian, we have 
$$
\|a^{n}\| =r(a^n) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \|a^{kn}\|^{1/k} = \left(\lim_{k\to\infty} \|a^{kn}\|^{1/(kn)}\right)^n = r(a)^n = \|a\|^n \tag{1}
$$

---

For completeness, the proof of $\|a\|=r(a)$ is based on the equality $\| a^{2^n}\|=\|a\| ^{2^n}$ which, as Kaladin noted in a comment, is shown by induction: 
$$\| a^{2^n}\| = \left\| \left(a^{2^{n-1}}\right)^2\right\|  = \| a^{2^{n-1}}\| ^2 = \dots =\|a\|^{2^n} \tag{2}$$
Since the limit $r(a) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \|a^k\|^{1/k}$ is known to exist (page 197), one can use (2) to calculate it along the subsequence $k_n=2^n$.

Comment: Would it work to use the fact that $a$ corresponds to the identity function under the isomorphism between the commutative $C^*$-algebra generated by $a$ and the continuous functions on the spectrum of $a$? Which approach do you think is more elementary?

Comment: The isomorphism theorem needs to be proved first, I suppose. In Conway, C* algebras have just been defined two pages ago, on p.232. But do feel free to post an answer based on the isomorphism.

Comment: I remember learning the proof you wrote down when I did learn about $C^*$-algebras a long time ago, but by that time, we already had the Gelfand transform at our disposal. Now I wonder why that is...

Comment: Alternatively, if one takes as known that the limit formula for $r(a)$ also gives the largest of the absolute values of elements of the spectrum (how I would think of it being defined), then the $r(a^n)=r(a)^n$ step doesn't require another invocation of the limit formula, as it would hold in any algebra.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, let $A$ be the $C^*$-algebra generated by $a$. Since $a$ is hermitian (or more generally normal), $A$ is commutative and isometrically isomorphic under the Gelfand transform to $(C(X),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$, where $X=\sigma(a)$ is the spectrum of $a$, and $a$ corresponds to the identity function of $X$; thus
$$\|a^n\|=\|\mathrm{id}_X^n\|_\infty=\|\mathrm{id}_X\|_\infty^n=\|a\|^n.$$

Comment: $a$ need not correspond to the identity.

Comment: @TomekKania It's been years since I learnt this stuff, and I've forgotten most about it, but I seem to remember that it did, and it seems to work for normal matrices. What element corresponds to the identity if not $a$?

Comment: Well, it is some element. What is the spectrum of the identity? Take any element with spectrum which is not $\{1\}$, it cannot play the role of the identity. By the way, the string of equalities you wrote would imply that $\|a\|^n=1$. I suggest deleting this answer.

Comment: @TomekKania But the spectrum of the identity function $\mathrm{id}_X$ is $X$, not $\lbrace 1\rbrace$, and $\|\mathrm{id}_X\|=\sup_{x\in X}|x|$ has no reason to be equal to $1$. I think you are completely misunderstanding my answer, I suggest reading my answer again.

Comment: Ah, I misread your post. Sorry about that.

Comment: @TomekKania No problem! I'm glad this has a happy ending ^^